# Did I define many to one correctly in the composite key?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have defined entities as the following:

```
@Entity
data class Environment(
    @EmbeddedId
    var key: EnvStageId? = null,
    var value: String = ""

)


@Embeddable
class EnvStageId(
    @ManyToOne
    var stage: Stage? = null,
    var key: String = ""
) : Serializable


@Entity
data class Stage(
    @field:Id
    var env: String = "",
    var description: String = ""

)
```

I used Hibernate and it generates the tables as expected. The question is, did I define `ManyToOne` correctly or did I miss something? Regarding this  [this](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many#models) tutorial, I have to define `ManyToOne` on one side and `OneToMany` on other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't **have to** define the other side of the relationship. You only have to do it if you **want to** have access to the relations from both side.

If you want to do that you'll have to do something like this. I'm not familiar with `@Embeddable`, but I imagine that it should be similar to this:

```
@Entity
data class Environment(
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "environment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    var stages: List<Stage>
)

@Entity
data class Stage(
    @ManyToOne
    var environment: Environment
)
```

Comment: Do I define the composite key correctly? Look at the class `EnvStageId`, the `@ManyToOne` is defined. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it should work, although I don't really see the point. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: It works as expected, but not sure, if it is correct or not. I can let like this right?

Comment: You can leave it like this, but it would be great if you could explain your use case. Maybe there is a better solution.